# Foxpro database and date, how?

Tags: database, date, foxpro

I'm working on a query from en Fox Pro Database. My problem is to find out which is the way to extract only 1 year/ 12 months from a Date.
This is my structure (simpleform):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE mydate = date()-interval(12,month).
```

MSQuery is responding with: Column month not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select * from table where between(mydate, gomonth(mydate, -12), mydate)
```